# Listar todos os estados no Node JS e Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

Tô tentando montar uma função para listar todos os estados e depois imprimir dentro de um objeto. Desculpe ser tão noob, acredito que seja um problema bem bobo.

Estados

```
    function listarTodasOsEstados(){
    var estado = [
        'AC',
'AL',
'AP',
'AM',
'BA',
'CE',
'DF',
'ES',
'GO',
'MA',
'MT',
'MS',
'MG',
'PA',
'PB',
'PR',
'PE',
'PI',
'RJ',
'RN',
'RS',
'RO',
'RR',
'SC',
'SP',
'SE',
'TO'
        ]

var mostrar_para_o_painel = console.log(estado);
return mostrar_para_o_painel;
};
```

Contexto:

```
User.add({
estado: { Types.Select, options: listarTodasOsEstados(), label:"Estado", initial:true} })
```

Resultado:

```
/home/pedromagalhaes/Projects/Projeto_Ag2/node_modules/keystone/fields/types/select/SelectType.js:21
        throw new Error('Select fields require an options array.');
        ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que sua função esta retornando `undefined`. Isso acontece porque sua função retorna uma variável que é o resultado de `console.log()`.

Não há necessidade de criar uma nova variável na penúltima linha da função (`mostrar_para_o_painel`). Basta trocar as linhas finasi para

```
console.log(estado);
return estado;
```